# PHP Check DB For Duplicate Number Before Adding New

Tags: select, for-loop, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress plugin and I am trying to generate a unique "pin" when adding a row to the table. The pin needs to be a number string (8 chars but that's not important). The table will save some user data and dates.

But what I am struggling with is making sure I have a unique pin before inserting the row. So far I have tried using an if statement, but that will only work if the random pin is matched once.

I'm using mt_rand to check the "pin" and then checking the DB to see if this pin exists (it must be unique). I think I need to do a for loop, but I struggling (only ever used foreach lopps)

So far I have this, but I know it's not right (it could work, but I would multiple nested ifs and it would be limited by the amount of ifs in place):

```
function pin_generator_create_pin(){
  global $wpdb;
   $pin = mt_rand(109076, 999999);

   if(!$wpdb->get_var("SELECT * FROM ".PIN_GENERATOR_TABLE." WHERE pin=".$pin)){
     return $pin;
   }else{

     $pin = mt_rand(109076, 999999);
       if(!$wpdb->get_var("SELECT * FROM ".PIN_GENERATOR_TABLE." WHERE pin=".$pin)){
       return $pin;
       }
   }
}//function
```

Can anyone see what I'm trying to do?

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a while loop, something like that:

```
function pin_generator_create_pin(){
    global $wpdb;

    $pin = 0;
    $pinExists = true;
    while ($pinExists) {
        $pin = mt_rand(109076, 999999);
        if(!$wpdb->get_var("SELECT * FROM ".PIN_GENERATOR_TABLE." WHERE pin=".$pin))
            $pinExists = false;
    }

    return $pin;
}//function
```

Comment: this is perfect, exactley was i needed.